# Codecademy - Looking for clarification on syntax ( === "number" )

Tags: javascript

I'm working my way through the Codecademy 'Intro to JavaScript' course. I've just came across an example section of code that has confused me a little and doesn't seem to be explained. I've looked at the Mozilla documentation and think I understand but I'm really just looking for clarification on the subject.

```
let restaurant = {
  _name: 'Italian Bistro',
  _seatingCapacity: 120,
  _hasDineInSpecial: true,
  _entrees: ['Penne alla Bolognese', 'Chicken Cacciatore', 'Linguine 
pesto'],

  set seatingCapacity(newCapacity) {
      if (typeof newCapacity === 'number') {        // THIS LINE
        this._seatingCapacity = newCapacity;
      console.log(`${newCapacity} is valid input.`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Change ${newCapacity} to a number.`)
    }
  }
```

My question - Does 'number' here mean a number (12, 343 etc.) rather than the string 'number' in all cases? Or is it only within the typeof operator?

I'm assuming it's a silly question but it's one that threw me off. Thanks.

Comment: Since you use `typeof newCapacity`, yes the condition will pass only when `newCapacity` is a numeric value (12, 343, etc). `typeof` yields values like `string`, `number`, `object`, etc. Each of these are returned as strings themselves.

Comment: "number" means the typeof newCapacity, that's a number. Check all types here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp

Comment: `typeof` returns a string.. So it's the type of the object, in this case your checking to see if it's a number.  And `number` here is a string, as that's the type.. :)

Answer (score 1):

`===` is used to check for strict equality. Consider the following example

```
0 == false //<== returns true
0 === false //<== returns false
```

In your example is not necessary, as `typeof` will never return any value that could be **equal** to `number` without being the `number` string itself. But it's considered good practice to use `===` (although I personally think it depends on what you are comparing)

(list of possible returned values for `typeof` here)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Yeah I was in the middle of editing my answer. but it depends on what you are comparing